# Django static tag prepending multiple http

Tags: python, django, django-templates

What are the appropriate Django settings for use with the [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) tag?

I have STATIC_URL set to:

```
STATIC_URL = '//myid.cloudfront.net/'
```

which is protocol-less so I can use it on secure and non-secure versions of my site.

But when I use it in a template like:

```
<img src="{% static 'i/myimg.png' %}" />
```

it renders as:

```
<img src="http:http:http:http:http:http:http:http:http:http://myid.cloudfront.net/i/myimg.png" />
```

What would be causing so many redundant "http:" being prepended?

Comment: What happens if you pass the {{ STATIC_URL }} before your file path instead of wrapping it up in {% static %}?